# Rendering expressions and axioms from an ontology using the OWL API

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I am using the OWL API to parse ontologies, the problem is that I can't get a 'pretty print' of the expressions. For example, given the next axiom:

```
EquivalentClasses(<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/generations.owl#OffSpring>
    ObjectIntersectionOf(<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/generations.owl#Person>
        ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/generations.owl#hasParent>
             <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/generations.owl#Person>)))
```

I would like to get a cleaner version of it, for example something like:

```
EquivalentClasses ( OffSpring,
    ObjectIntersectionOf (Person, ObjectSomeValuesFrom (hasParent, Person)))
```

I got the example ontology from [here](https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/attachment/wiki/IntroductionToOntologiesWithProtege/family_example.owl).

Comment: 2 ways: a) either you explicitly use an instance of the  `OWLObjectRenderer` interface and call the `render(ax)` method or b) if you want to have it shortened each time toString is called anywhere you could change the renderer (resp. the `ShortFormProvider`) by the utility class `org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.ToStringRenderer` (see http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_2_3/org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/ToStringRenderer.html)

Comment: @AKSW I'd make this comment an answer

Comment: Can you change the question title? This is not really about parsing, it's about rendering.

Comment: @Ignazio , of course.

Comment: @AKSW , sorry, I gave it a try but I can't get it to work, I am new in Java (therefore, new with OWL API too), so, can you provide me a short example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other [OWLObjectRenderer](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/OWLObjectRenderer.html): *DLSyntaxObjectRenderer, LatexOWLObjectRenderer, ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl, SimpleRenderer, SimpleRendererDebug*

Here is an example of replacing the default OWLObjectRenderer (SimpleRenderer) into the ToStringRenderer:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.ToStringRenderer;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLObjectRenderer;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.renderer.ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl;

...

ToStringRenderer.setRenderer(new Provider<OWLObjectRenderer>() {
    @Override
    public OWLObjectRenderer get() {
        return new ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl();
    }
});
```